# Sorting records in unix

Tags: unix

On Unix: I have a text file that has records that I need to sort in ascending order of date and time. I have looked at the sort command and couldn't get it to work for me. Could someone please help me with this? Or point me in the right direction?

```
{
  DateAndTime : "2010-08-27-11.42.43.082-0400",
  TestString:"123",
   TestData : {
    { field0 : "1234" },
    { field1 : "5678" }
              }
}

{
  DateAndTime : "2010-08-28-11.43.43.082-0400",
  TestString:"123",
   TestData : {
    { field0 : "1234" },
    { field1 : "5678" }
               }
}
```

Comment: `sort` could help if these records where one-per-line. Here you should probably write a script in Python/Perl/Ruby. Hint: this format looks pretty much like JSON, for which there are libraries to parse in all of these languages.

Answer (score 0):

Reading file line by line using awk or read will help.

cat test | while read field1 $field2 ; do sorting with field1 and prev_field1; prev_field1=field1 ; done